# Swap two values in a list of lists (python)

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to swap every occurrence of two elements in a list of lists. I have seen previous answers but they are different from what I'm trying to do. Also, I am looking for a clean and concise way (preferably list-comprehension) for this purpose.

**Input**

```
my_list = [[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [3,2]]
```

**Output**

```
my_list = [[2,1], [2,3], [2,4], [3,1]]
```

I am trying to do something like this but no success:

```
[1 if i==2 else i, 2 if i==1 else i for i in my_list]
```

Comment: Can you please clarify why is the output `[[2,1], [2,3], [2,4], [3,1]]` as opposed to `[[2, 1], [3, 1], [4, 1], [2, 3]]`?

Comment: @joe733 op wants to swap every occurrence of 1 with 2 and vice-versa

Comment: @heitor oh I see, thanks!

Comment: @heitor See my updated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63986140).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple solution using list comprehension:

```py
my_list = [[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [3,2]]

a = 1
b = 2
my_list = [[a if i==b else b if i==a else i for i in j] for j in my_list]

print(my_list) # [[2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1]]
```

If you want to add more elements to replace you can use a dictionary:

```py
swap = {
    1: 2,
    2: 1
}

my_list = [[swap.get(i, i) for i in j] for j in my_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone else will probably answer with something better, but this would work.

```
def check(num):
    if num == 1:
        return 2
    elif num == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return num

out = [[check(j) for j in i] for i in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to swap `1`'s with `2`'s, this one-liner will work:

```py
>>> my_list = [[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [3,2]]
>>> print([[(lambda k: (1 if val == 2 else 2) if val in [1, 2] else val)(val) for val in sub_list] for sub_list in my_list])
[[2, 1], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 1]]
```

> read the second line from right to left... in chunks!

Comment: This code is interchanging the positions of elements in sub-lists, the original question is asking something different. That is to replace 1 with 2 and 2 with 1 throughout the list.

Comment: The headline is a bit misguiding. I clarified my doubt from the comments below the question. I've updated my answer to meet op's requirements. Thanks anyway!